# refresh div on parent page after some processing triggered by a submit button

Tags: php, jquery

I want to refresh a div on a parent page after the child page have finished some processing triggered by a submit button and then close the child window. any ideas are welcomed.

Script used to open the child page, parent.php :

```
$(function(){
  $('#right').on({
        click: function(){
                     window.open('child.php', 'Delivery choice', 'width=600,height=600');
                         }
                },'.ship'); 
});
```

Here is the child.php :

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<div style="background: transparent url(images/bg2.png) repeat-y scroll 0% 50%;"><form action="deliverydata.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="1">
 <tr><th>Code</th><th>Service de livraison</th><th>Prix</th><th>Delais de livraison</th><th>Choisir</th></tr>
 <?php
            function connectMaBase(){
            $base = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', '');  
            mysql_select_db ('artisant', $base) ;
            }
            connectMaBase();
            $sql ='SELECT * from categ_livraison';
            $res = mysql_query ($sql) or die ('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());
            while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) != null)
            {  
                echo '<tr><td>'.$row['num_categ_livraison'].'</td><td>'.$row['designation'].'</td><td>'.$row['frais'].'</td><td>'.$row['jours'].'</td><td><input type="radio" name="deli" value="'.$row['num_categ_livraison'].'"/></td></tr>';
            }
            echo '</table><div style="padding: right; margin: 40px 100px 100px 375px;"><input type="submit" name="valider" value="  OK   " /></div></form></div>';
            mysql_close();
            if (isset($_POST['valider'])){
            connectMaBase();
            $sql = 'UPDATE produit SET categorie_livraison ="'.$_POST['deli'].'" WHERE num_prod='.$_SESSION['num_prod'];
            $res = mysql_query ($sql) or die ('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());
            mysql_close();
            echo "<script>window.close();</script>";}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "parent page" and "child page", but if you want to submit a form and refresh the contents of a div based on the result of the form submission you can use an Ajax method written in jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        var url = form.attr('action');
        var data = form.serialize();
        $.post(url, data)
            .done(function() {
                $('#myDiv').html(data)
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert('Uh oh, something went wrong. Please try again');
            });
    });

});
```

Comment: I mean that parent.php opens a new window (child.php) using window.open() method. I updatet the thread

Comment: I think you should make it a single page app and use Ajax. It doesn't make such sense try to shuffle the data (not to mention the user) back and forth between two different pages. Maybe open the "child page" form as a modal instead of a separate page.